# How to use a formula that references a column from an input box selection in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that comes in from new customers and different vendors sporadically. There is not set standard to the files. The number of columns vary per customer, but there is always a customer first name column, last name column, and ID column with leading zeros somewhere in the file.
Often times, the leading zeros are dropped and so the file needs to have that column reformatted and I normally manually have to go through and create a separate column to do a "=TEXT(F2,"00000000")" if the field happens to be in column F for this customer.
Is there any way I can create a VBA script to get user input from an input box to point to the column letter/number and then set that range as a variable where I can then use the input in my formula? Or a better easier way? I haven't been able to find anyone doing this in my search so far (maybe because there is a better way I am not thinking about?).
Note: I understand I am doing the formula as a string, so it is reading the variable that way - not sure how else to bring that range or even a selected cell address in to reference in the formula.
I would like it to be something like
**First Name | Last Name | ID**  
John       | Doe       | 123 
Then the script adds the column ID Re-Formatted: 
**First Name | Last Name | ID  | ID Re-Formatted** 
John       | Doe       | 123 | 
But I can't figure out how to Have the user select the ID column so it can be used to autofill and format with the leading zeros in the reformatted column to look like this after doing the "=TEXT(rng,"00000000")" : 
**First Name | Last Name | ID  | ID Re-Formatted** 
John       | Doe       | 123 | 00000123 
Thanks for any pointers and help!

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Add a column for the ID to be reformatted with leading zeros
With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = "ID Re-Formatted"
    .Cells(LastCol + 1).Select
    .Cells(LastCol + 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

'Get A Column Address From The User for the Original ID Column
 On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
     Title:="ID Column Selection", _
    Prompt:="Select column containing ID", _
    Type:=8)
  On Error GoTo 0

 Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1)).Formula = "=TEXT(rng,""00000000000"")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get the Range object into your formula you just need to use concatenation.  Stop the String at `"=TEXT("`, then do your concatenation of the Range object using an `&` either side.  You then just need another `"` before the rest of the formula.  It would look like the following.

`Range(Cells(2, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1)).Formula = "=TEXT(" & rng & ",""00000000000"")"`

Update:
Sorry, `rng` does contain the contents, you can use `rng.Address` but as you pointed out, you always get the same cell reference.  That's because when the person selects the cell, it's selecting it as an Absolute Reference.  This isn't the most elegant means, but this will remove the `$`.  You are reading the Range Address into a String variable and then replacing the $ with nothing.  This effectively changes your reference to Relative.

```
Dim rngStr As String
rngStr = rng.Address
rngStr = Replace(rngStr, "$", "")
```

Then in your formula, use `rngStr` instead of `rng`

Comment: That makes sense - Now if user input is $F$2, it populates the whole reformatted column with the contents of F2. Do I just need to do a basic formula instead of the range formula I have to populate the reformatted 2nd row and then run a selection.autofill?  Thanks

Comment: @jlyle  did the extra info help?